# Append then focus on child input query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a div with a child input (this is working fine) however I cannot get the newly appended input to 'focus'.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap_ex1"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button_ex1"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(this).parent().parent().append('<div id="setsdiv" class="col-xs-12 text-center"><div class="col-xs-8"><input id="set" class="form-control input-sm setinput text-center" type="text" name="ex1[]" placeholder="W / R" pattern="\\d*"></div><div class="col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-xs btn-default remove_field  pull-right">Remove</a></div></div>'); //add input box
        }

    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })

});
```

The 'setsdiv' is appending but I cannot focus the input with ID 'set'.

Keep in mind that I cannot just set .focus('set') because I may have multiple the more I append.

Comment: if you are appending new element it will make **duplicate ID** , `ID should always be unique` , use class instead

Comment: Where is `.focus()` called ?

Comment: So you can't focus on it or you want to make it focused when you create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have alluded to, it'd be simpler to employ `classes` here instead of `ids`. Then you can just use something like `.find('.set:last').focus();`  to set focus on the last element with that class which will be the one you just added.

Without knowing quite how your HTML is structured, here is an example that should illustrate the concept:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap_ex1"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button_ex1"); //Add button 
    $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
        
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('.setsdiv').length < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            $container=$(this).parent().parent();
            $container.append('<div class="col-xs-12 text-center setsdiv"><div class="col-xs-8"><input class="form-control input-sm setinput text-center set" type="text" name="ex1[]" placeholder="W / R" pattern="\\d*"></div><div class="col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-xs btn-default remove_field  pull-right">Remove</a></div></div>'); //add input box
            $container.find('.set:last').focus();
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.setsdiv').remove();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap_ex1">
    <div>
        <button class="add_field_button_ex1">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using variable `x` to concatenate to `id` of appended `div` , `input` elements to avoid duplicate `id`s ; call `.focus()` on appended `input` element having `id` ending with variable `x` ; increment variable

```
   var x = 1;
   $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
     e.preventDefault();
     if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed           
       $(this).parent().parent()
       .append('<div id="setsdiv"'+x+' class="col-xs-12 text-center"><div class="col-xs-8"><input id="set"'+x+' class="form-control input-sm setinput text-center" type="text" name="ex1[]" placeholder="W / R" pattern="\\d*"></div><div class="col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-xs btn-default remove_field  pull-right">Remove</a></div></div>') //add input box
       .find("input[type=text][id$="+x+"]").focus(); 
       x++; //text box increment;           
     }        
   });
```

```js
var x = 1, html = "<div id=abc"+x+"><input type=text id=def"+x+" /></div>";
$("body").append(html).find("input[type=text][id$="+x+"]").focus()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```